# Java Error: cannot find symbol yet the variables are declared?

Tags: java, variables, symbols

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment1Q3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the first time: ");
    int fTime = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter second time: ");
    int lTime = in.nextInt();
    int tDifference = Math.abs(fTime - lTime);
    String strTDiff = String.valueOf(tDifference);
    int length = strTDiff.length();
    if (length == 4)
    {
        String hours = strTDiff.substring(0, 2);
        String minutes = strTDiff.substring(3, 5);
    }
    else if (length == 3)
    {
        String hours = strTDiff.substring(0);
        String minutes = strTDiff.substring(2, 4);
    }
    else
    {
        String hours = ("0");
        String minutes = strTDiff.substring(0, 1);
    }
    System.out.println(hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes");
    }
}
```

Hey guys so im attempting to make a simple program using Java to find the difference between 2 times given in military time and to give the output in number of hours and minutes. Whenever i compile this in command prompt it gives me an error for the variable hours and the variable minutes in the last printing line saying "cannot find symbol". I thought trying to declare them before the if statement but that did not work either. I apologize but i am very new to programming and appreciate any help offered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By calling String within  the if statements they only exist within the if statement you need to decalre them outside of the if and associate a value within the if.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assignment1Q3
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the first time: ");
    int fTime = in.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter second time: ");
    int lTime = in.nextInt();
    int tDifference = Math.abs(fTime - lTime);
    String strTDiff = String.valueOf(tDifference);
    int length = strTDiff.length();
    String hours = "";
    String minutes = "";

    if (length == 4)
    {
        hours = strTDiff.substring(0, 2);
        minutes = strTDiff.substring(3, 5);
    }
    else if (length == 3)
    {
        hours = strTDiff.substring(0);
        minutes = strTDiff.substring(2, 4);
    }
    else
    {
        hours = ("0");
        minutes = strTDiff.substring(0, 1);
    }
    System.out.println(hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes");
    }
}
```

so you can initialise them to "" or to remove unnecessary else statement initialise them to the else valuse

```
    String hours = "0";
    String minutes = strTDiff.substring(0, 1);

    if (length == 4)
    {
        hours = strTDiff.substring(0, 2);
        minutes = strTDiff.substring(3, 5);
    }
    else if (length == 3)
    {
        hours = strTDiff.substring(0);
        minutes = strTDiff.substring(2, 4);
    }
System.out.println(hours + " hours " + minutes + " minutes");
```

Answer (score 2):

When you define a object reference or any primitive variable inside a `if` block (or any such block), it is accessible only within that block.

Change as below

```
final String hours, minutes;
if (length == 4)
{
    hours = strTDiff.substring(0, 2);
    minutes = strTDiff.substring(3, 5);
}
else if (length == 3)
{
    hours = strTDiff.substring(0);
    minutes = strTDiff.substring(2, 4);
}
else
{
    hours = ("0");
    minutes = strTDiff.substring(0, 1);
}
```

Comment: oh so i must make 3 seperate outputs for each sub block?

Comment: No need to assign them to `null`.  Let the compiler help you and ensure that all code paths initialise them.

Comment: Was about to say that. And make them `final` if possible.

Comment: @GregKopff C/C++ habit, fixed

Comment: oh wow that worked, thanks alot but what exactly does the null command do? I have never been introduced to it before.

Comment: @user2023740 as others have commented, that is unnecessary. I was just initializing it to `null`, but that is the default in Java anyway, and they are definitely going to be initialized in the rest of the code.

Comment: @user2023740 if all code path did not initialize them, then you can actually initialize them to the empty string or "" as Sean has in his answer.

Comment: oh wow i actually tried that but i put parenthesis around the quotations.. thanks alot for the help

Comment: @user2023740: the best thing about the code block above is that the compiler will ensure that each and every code path initialises those two variables to something. If you accidentally included a code path where they were left unset, the compiler would complain (this is a good thing!).  Also, declaring them as final makes sure that you can only ever assign a value once.  If you accidentally had a bug where you set the value a second time, the compiler would detect it and complain (again, a good thing!).